# Git merge dropped more recent code

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

It's been an year since I started using git on a 3 person team, this is the first time i cannot understand why git is punishing me.

I have the main branch develop.

On Sep/2013 i created branch 'topics' from 'develop' and started working on it.

On Oct/2013 i created branch 'fixOct' from 'develop' and started working on it.

On the file 'wsCommesse.cs' i had function A, C, D.

On branch 'topics' i added some comments to function D.

On branch 'fixOct' i added a lengthy function B between functions A and C; then i modified many lines inside function D.

Today i tried to merge 'topics' with 'fixOct'.
I received a merging conflict warning me that git didn't know if he had to add the function B (ok), but threw all the code changed in function D, keeping the comment edited on branch 'topics' (catastrophic).

I searched documentation on why this happened, tried different merge strategies, patience, logging, verbose; git sees no conflict in function D, he just feel that that code has to be thrown away.

Only way to keep it was to use 'merge -s ours topics', but this kills the merge intelligence.

Why doesn't he warn me of a conflict ?
Why he thinks it's safe to kill the more fresh code ? 
How can i prevent similar problems in the future, even adding more hand checked conflicts ?

I attach a diff screenshot of what happened, using bitbucket web interface.
In red the more recent code that was removed with the merge.
In green the older code that remained after the merge.

[image]

Same code, side-by-side diff
[image]

Thanks in advance,
Fabrizio

Comment: My first attempt would be to split the commit causing git trouble with `rebase -i`.  Without seeing the actual content (merge base, ours, theirs) it's going to be hard to say what's confusing git's merge algorithm.

Comment: @jthill both the branches come from 'develop'.
on which branch should i run rebase ?

I understand it's hard to have an answer without actual code, i thought it was more a conceptual problem; still, having the problem on one specific file, i'll try to post what i find once you tell me on what i should run rebase:
- on topics before merge ?

- on fixOct before merge ?

- on fixOct after merge ?

Comment: Read up on interactive rebase, you do it on the branch with the problematic history.

Comment: @jthill ok, done it, went on the branch that loses code (fixOct) and 'execute rebase -i topics'.
I have exactly the same output i had with the merge, some code warns conflicts, but some code is just overriden, no warning, nothing to watch at.

Comment: @jthill tried also in the other direction, i still have the same problem. 
More recent code remove, no warning.

Comment: @jthill added screenshot of the problem in then original question, hoping to explain better my problem.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing the code as at what git believe's is the correct merge base for the 3-way diff and what you believe it should have been.

Comment: @CharlesBailey ok, what can i do to hilight it ? Rebased or merge tells me nothing.
I've tried putting screenshot that compares the code, if you can suggest me the command i'll be glad to paste the source

Comment: You have two commits that were merged so you should be able to find a merge base that git chose with `git merge-base <commita> <commitb>`. If you look at the file as at that commit you may find the answer.

Comment: @CharlesBailey the merge-base helped me, the ancestor i received wasn't the one i expected, and in the common ancestor the code i 'lost' was already present. I still don't get why it was dumped.

Comment: What that basically tells you is that that commit (and the hence the lost code) was merged into both branches that you merged together but on one side either that merge was done in a way that threw out the code or that code was subsequently reverted. The other side probably left the code alone so the only effect of merging a "no-change" and a "removal" to that code is to do the removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jthill and @charlesBailey have been helpful in the comments, i have not found a 'real' solution, and i'm out of time to spend on this issue; i'll just write what i found and hope it will help someone else.

At the base of the problem there is probably a human error, someone marged a recent update and then threw away a part of the code while handling conflicts, causing that code to be thrown at the successive merge.

The key to understand this was using the command `git merge-base <commita> <commitb>` that compares two branches and tell you what is the common commit ancestor that will be used for future merges between the two.

I found that the ancestor was way more recent than i thought and that already contained the code i thought to be just in one of the branches; the code that got lost at the final merge.

I think that learning better the use of `rebase` would help to mitigate this issue but at the moment i'll keep using the `merge --no-ff` filosophy and try to keep a low cuncurrent branch count.

Cheers,
Fabrizio